# Mounting an AFP share over/to ~/Pictures, possible stale share issue (Mac OS X, Big Sur)

Tags: mac, mount, network-shares, fstab

I'm trying to over mount an AFP share onto `~/Pictures`, and it's not quite working for some reason.

Useful information:

- I'm using AutoMounter (Pro features enabled, full-disk access granted via System Prefs).
- I was successful over mounting onto `~/Music`.
- I can't get `~/Pictures` to work.
- Initially, I got an error (Console) about  `~/Pictures` not being empty, so I did `rm -rf *` within `~/Pictures`.
- I then got an error (again, via the Console app) about a stale share at `~/Pictures`.
- I deleted `~/Pictures` altogether, and recreated it (via Finder).
- Now, when I try to tell AutoMounter to (re-) try mounting the share, Console again shows stale mount point messages, and when cleaning up, removes `~/Pictures`.

I *think* where I am is that the OS believes there's another `~/Pictures`, or something already mounted to `~/Pictures`.

Where would a stale link be "retained" or identified by the OS? There's no `/etc/fstab` or other usual suspects, and nothing even remotely close shows up via `ls -la`.

Thanks!

Console output:

```
7AB2-474A-BCEF-77D7EFA9F42B from AutoMounterHelper (904)
default 12:57:09.952909-0500    NetAuthSysAgent URL = afp://share_username@10.1.1.13/Pictures
default 12:57:09.952569-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Share: 'Pictures' started to mount with URL: afp://share_username@10.1.1.13/Pictures
default 12:57:09.952651-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Share: 'Pictures' mount request status: 0
default 12:57:09.953888-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Session created

default 12:57:09.959887-0500    NetAuthSysAgent GetServerInfo serverParamsDict = {
    GuestOnly = 0;
    MountedByUser = share_username;
    NetFSMachineType = "Netatalk3.1.8";
    ServerDisplayName = "10.1.1.13";
    SupportsChangePassword = 0;
    SupportsGuest = 0;
}
default 12:57:09.960110-0500    NetAuthSysAgent CredentialsStage set to 4
default 12:57:09.960207-0500    NetAuthSysAgent SecKeychainSetUserInteractionAllowed(false) secKeychainStatus = 0

default 12:57:09.983395-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Found Server Marker for "10.1.1.13"
default 12:57:09.983409-0500    NetAuthSysAgent SecKeychainSetUserInteractionAllowed(interactionAllowed) secKeychainStatus = 0
default 12:57:09.983434-0500    NetAuthSysAgent User has visited this machine before
default 12:57:09.983464-0500    NetAuthSysAgent isKnownServer 1
default 12:57:09.983613-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Unable to find matching items -25300

default 12:57:09.988410-0500    NetAuthSysAgent (76) /System/Library/CoreServices/NetAuthAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/NetAuthSysAgent
default 12:57:09.988434-0500    NetAuthSysAgent (45) /System/Library/CoreServices/NetAuthAgent.app
default 12:57:09.988450-0500    NetAuthSysAgent (15) group://NetAuth
default 12:57:09.995162-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Calling OpenSession:
default 12:57:09.995193-0500    NetAuthSysAgent     server afp://share_username:********@10.1.1.13/Pictures
error   12:57:09.998681-0500    NetAuthSysAgent settings cache entry missing
error   12:57:09.999183-0500    NetAuthSysAgent settings cache entry missing

default 12:57:10.229955-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Session Info = {
    MountedByUser = share_username;
}
default 12:57:10.231235-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Calling Mount
default 12:57:10.231295-0500    NetAuthSysAgent     URL = afp://share_username@10.1.1.13/Pictures
default 12:57:10.231322-0500    NetAuthSysAgent     Mount point = /Users/administrator

error   12:57:10.249876-0500    kernel  System Policy: NetAuthSysAgent(14220) deny(1) file-mount /Users/administrator/Pictures
default 12:57:10.264447-0500    NetAuthSysAgent ERROR: AFP_Mount - theEnumerator->Mount failed 1
error   12:57:10.264631-0500    kernel  System Policy: NetAuthSysAgent(14220) deny(1) file-write-unlink /Users/administrator/Pictures
default 12:57:10.264678-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Mount failed 1
default 12:57:10.265564-0500    NetAuthSysAgent CloseSession result 0
default 12:57:10.265716-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Share: '/Pictures' mount return status: 1
default 12:57:10.265640-0500    NetAuthSysAgent Reply Connect to Server status = 1
default 12:57:10.265841-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Share: 'Pictures' problem mounting network volume with url: afp://share_username@10.1.1.13/Pictures. Mount Failed. Error code: 1.
default 12:57:10.265902-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Share: 'Pictures' failed mount request left stale path at: /Users/administrator/Pictures.
default 12:57:10.266400-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Share: 'Pictures' - Attempting to remove stale path: /Users/administrator/Pictures
default 12:57:10.266606-0500    AutoMounterHelper   Successfully removed stale mount: /Users/administrator/Pictures
default 12:57:10.266733-0500    AutoMounterHelper   HELPER: ERROR: Share mount failed with id 025A93A5-AF0C-428D-967E-46ED27D88EA1. Sending Notification back to AutoMounter.
default 12:57:10.267450-0500    AutoMounter Helper: Share 'Pictures' failed to mount share notification recieved
default 12:57:10.267541-0500    AutoMounter Share: 'Pictures' changed state to: 'unmounted'
```